# function to determine if ISO 8601 date is after X days

Tags: linux, bash, date, datetime

I'd like a bash function which returns true or false depending on if the date passed (in ISO 8601 format) is after X number of days.

An example of ISO 8601 date format is - 2017-05-19T01:57:41Z

The function must be pure bash and preferably work on OSX & Debian Linux. Please state why if this is not possible.

Thank you

Comment: Please show your coding efforts, SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

For systems where GNU coreutils date is available, you could use the `-d` option to pass custom dates, and the `+%s` modifier to get a timestamp:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=${1:-'2017-05-29T01:57:41Z'} 
input_ts=$(date -d "$input" +%s)

limit="now +${2:-5} days"
limit_ts=$(date -d "$limit" +%s)

if (( $input_ts > $limit_ts ))
then 
  echo "$input is after $limit"
else
  echo "$input is before $limit"
fi
```

Some tests:

```
$ ./script.sh
2017-05-29T01:57:41Z is after now +5 days

$ ./script.sh 2013/1/1
2013/1/1 is before now +5 days

$ ./script.sh '' 10
2017-05-29T01:57:41Z is before now +10 days

$ ./script.sh '2031/12/2' 10
2031/12/2 is after now +10 days
```